# How to login using mediawiki API?

Tags: api, curl, mediawiki, wiki, wikipedia

```
$ch=curl_init();
$postfield = "action=login&lgname=d&lgpassword=Password&format=json";
$url = "http://wiki.signa.com/api.php"; //url to wiki's api

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfield);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);


$output = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
curl_close($ch);

print_r($output);
$token = $output->login->token;
$session = $output->login->sessionid;

$ch=curl_init();

$postfield = "action=login&lgname=d&lgpassword=Password&lgtoken={$token}";
$url = "http://wiki.signa.com/api.php"; //url to wiki's api

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfield);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

print_r($output);
die;
```

With the first request I get this object:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [login] => stdClass Object
        (
            [result] => NeedToken
            [token] => ad61fadb829e5cd44b0062463b7cc2d2
            [cookieprefix] => wikisign_mediawiki
            [sessionid] => ebb892881eed27554161234916d00480
        )

)
```

I'm using the token to do a second request, but I get result = NeedToken.  It should be success since I'm sending the token now.

I noticed the documentation says:

> Send a login request with POST, with confirmation token in body and the session cookie (e.g. `enwiki_session`) in header as returned from previous request.

I'm not totally clear on that.  I'm assuming I'm having issues because I'm not sending the session cookie in the header.  Do I need to set a cookie prior to the second request?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to process all Set-Cookie Headers to login succesfully.
Documentation is [very specific](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Login) on this:

> This request will also return a session cookie in the HTTP header
>   (Set-Cookie: enwikiSession=17ab96bd8ffbe8ca58a78657a918558e; path=/;
>   domain=.wikipedia.org; HttpOnly) that you have to return for the
>   second request if your framework does not do this automatically
>
> A successful action=login request will set cookies needed to be
>   considered logged in. Many frameworks will handle these cookies
>   automatically (such as the cookiejar in cURL). If so, by all means
>   take advantage of this. If not, the most reliable method is to parse
>   them from the HTTP response's Set-Cookie headers.

Answer (score 1):

It's an old subject, but I'll answer for those who are interested :)
In fact you need to keep your cookies in a file and use them again in your second attempt to login.
Something like that :

```
$path_cookie = 'connexion_temporaire.txt';
if (!file_exists($path_cookie)) touch($path_cookie); 


$postfields = array(
        'action' => 'login',
        'format'=> 'json',
        'lgname' => $login,
        'lgpassword' => $pass
);

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $lienTestWiki);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $path_cookie); // you put your cookie in the file
$connexion=curl_exec($curl);
$json_connexion = json_decode($connexion, true);
$tokenConnexion=$json_connexion['login']['token']; // you take the token and keep it in a var for your second login

// /!\ don't close the curl conection or initialize a new one or your session id will change !

$postfields = array(
        'action' => 'login',
        'format'=> 'json',
        'lgtoken' => $tokenConnexion,
        'lgname' => $login,
        'lgpassword' => $pass

);


curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $lienTestWiki);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $path_cookie); //get the previous cookie
$connexionToken=curl_exec($curl);

var_dump($connexionToken);
```

When running this you should see a success this time :)

Comment: But how do you save to cookie to remain logged in after?